# Google Search is showing my website in Japanese instead of English

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, language

When my site is searched for in Google, it shows the website in Japanese (see the second link in the screenshot below), however the entire website is in English.

Does anyone know why this might be?

[image]

Comment: I think your site has been hacked.   You should should use Google's help section to fix the problem: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/

Answer (score 2):

Did you recently buy that domain?

[Google has a completely different page in its cache.](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IXyw3AgSN0MJ:https://metroinstitute.co.in/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)

You can tell Google to re-crawl the page and update their index using Google Search Console. Or, if you don't have/want a GSC property set up, testing your URL on their [Mobile Friendly Test](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly) tool can also accomplish the same thing.

Comment: No the Domain is around a year old, recently renewed.
But the issue has started before the renewal of the domain

Comment: When was it renewed?

Comment: It was renewed on 26/12/2019
I am a Noob
can you please help me like how can i request Google to re-crawl the page

Comment: [Add your property](https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome) (domain) in Google Search Console.
Then use the URL Inspection Tool within GSC and [request reindexing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289#request_indexing).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of `spam-seo?japanese.0` malware in WordPress. Update WordPress to the latest version.